# How to install tomcat7 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS using apt

Tags: apt, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to install tomcat 7 on an Ubuntu VM.  I've tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

but all I get is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tomcat7
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi user535733 the universal repository is already enabled for all sources

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Hmm when I try to add universe: sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

Comment: Bionic has tomcat8. 16.04 seems to be the last supported release which has tomcat7 in official repositories.

Comment: Ahh think there's an issue with the vagrant basebox I'm using will try with another base

Answer (score 0):

tomcat7 has been upgraded to tomcat8 in Ubuntu 18.04. tomcat8 is provided by the universe repository which you already have enabled. To install tomcat8 in 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install tomcat8
```